# Can Pandas DataFrames with ~500,000 columns be processed on a personal computer?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to use scikit-learn's `KMeans` algorithm to cluster a group of sets based on overlap. There are roughly 500,000 potential members of each set (though each set itself isn't too large).

It is my understanding that to use sklearn's `KMeans` implementation, I would need to represent each set as in 500,000-space with each column representing a binary value.

Is this too large for a personal computer to process. Is there a more efficient way to perform this operation?

Comment: Whats the configuration of your PC?It does look too large for an ordinary PC

Comment: @Dark off-the-shelf 2016 machine - think average laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on your data structure, but if you've got a 500k samples x N sets array that's mostly (~95%+) sparse, I would not expect too much trouble. Even if it was dense, 500k x 50 float64s is like... 200mb?

A better question would be "Is euclidian distance really a good way to measure distance between my sets", I think.

Comment: You have a good enough understanding of the data structure and I agree, that is a better to phrase the question. What is a better way (out-of-the-box algorithm) to measure distance between these sets?

Comment: You should choose a [distance metric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) that makes sense for your data. I don't think I can give you any useful advice without more information. I'm also not sure you can cluster with non-euclidean distances with `sklearn.clusters.KMeans` - maybe try DBSCAN instead?

Comment: Kmeans as a starting point is ok. Lasso, ridge regressions, GLM and random forests then beacon :-)